# Unix FIFO in go?

Tags: unix, go, pipe, fifo

Is there any way to create a unix FIFO with Go language? There is no `Mkfifo`, nor `Mknod` in `os` package, though I expected named FIFOs are largely used in posix OS's. In fact, there is a function for creating an unnamed FIFO (pipe), but no function for creating named pipes.

Am I the only one who needs them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get it to work on Linux, I simply did a

```
syscall.Mknod(fullPath, syscall.S_IFIFO|0666, 0)
```

It seemed to do the trick.

[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mknod) is a reference for the underlying mknod() call

Answer (score 3):

There is a `Mkfifo`, but it's in the [`syscall`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mkfifo)-package :)

Searching through the source gives me the feeling it's not available on anything but OS X and FreeBSD though: http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=Mkfifo+package:http://go%5C.googlecode%5C.com

I don't have a unix machine ready to test with. You can use `cgo` if you like to build a C-interface package which exports it for you.

Comment: Thanks! And you are right, on linux it says: `undefined syscall.Mkfifo`. So, will wait for linux support.

Comment: Just to update this, [`syscall.Mkfifo`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mkfifo) (and [`unix.Mkfifo`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Mkfifo)) now exist for most OSes supported by Go (the notable exceptions are windows and plan9). Also, using `syscall` or `golang.org/x/sys/unix` (with appropriate build constraints) should be preferred over `cgo`.